# Deny Checkout if Street Address is on blacklist WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I am using the code below and the aim and purpose is to block certain street addresses from being able to order. The code does not work (orders can still be made using any of the addresses blocked) though and I am wondering why.

Here is the code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'validate_address_for_spam_order' );
function validate_address_for_spam_order() {
$disableAddressList = array (
'Street name 1',
'Street name 2',
'Street name 3',
'Street name 4',
);
$billingAddress = isset( $_POST['billing_address_1'] ) ? trim( $_POST['billing_address_1'] ) : '';
$billingAddress = str_replace(array('-','_'),' ',$billingAddress);
$billingAddress = ucwords($billingAddress);
if (in_array($billingAddress, $disableAddressList))
{
wc_add_notice( __( 'Your error message here' ), 'error' );
}
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you has is working fine except with some logical issues . I have checked the code and it didn't work for me in the following case

- When address is Street Name 1 i.e, capital letters and small letters mixed in address ( Your array has Street name 1 and your  php function only converts first Letter to Caps). So Street NAme 1, StReeT NaMe 1, STREEt Name1  on comparison gives false results.

So you will have to change the method of comparing addresses . I choose the following which is applicable in most string comparisons.

- Write your disbaled address array in small letters

> ```
> $disableAddressList = array (
> 'street name 1',
> 'street name 2',
> 'street name 3',
> 'street name 4',
> );
> ```

- Instead of `ucwords()`, use `strtolower()`.

So the code will be

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'validate_address_for_spam_order' );
function validate_address_for_spam_order() {
    $disableAddressList = array (
        'street name 1',
        'street name 2',
        'street name 3',
        'street name 4',
    );
    $billingAddress = isset( $_POST['billing_address_1'] ) ? trim( $_POST['billing_address_1'] ) : '';
    $billingAddress = str_replace(array('-','_'),' ',$billingAddress);
    $billingAddress = strtolower($billingAddress);
    if (in_array($billingAddress, $disableAddressList))
    {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Your error message here' ), 'error' );
    }
}
```

Comment: I did, with pleasure :)